# Invalid object name 'dbo.GetProductOptionInformation'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on this issue and got an error message as below.
    Invalid object name 'dbo.GetProductOptionInformation'

```
The function is already exists on the database. I do not know what is the problem with this. 
Please point me where this problem would have.

SELECT 
  ProductOptionInformation.ID AS ID
, ProductOptionInformation.PRODUCT_ID AS [PRODUCT_ID]
, ProductOptionInformation.OPTION_NAME AS [OPTION_NAME]
, ProductOptionInformation.SUBOPTION_ID AS [SUBOPTION_ID]
, ProductOptionInformation.IS_SUBOPTION_REQUIRED AS [IS_SUBOPTION_REQUIRED]
, ProductOptionInformation.OPTION_PRICE AS [OPTION_PRICE]
, ProductOptionInformation.OPTION_DEFAULT_PRICE AS [OPTION_DEFAULT_PRICE]
, ProductOptionInformation.CATEGORY_NAME AS [CATEGORY_NAME]
, ProductOptionInformation.IS_MULTI_SELECT AS [IS_MULTI_SELECT]
, ProductOptionInformation.IS_SELECTION_REQUIRED AS [IS_SELECTION_REQUIRED]
, ProductOptionInformation.IS_DEFAULT AS [IS_DEFAULT]
, ProductOptionInformation.IS_SELECTED AS [IS_SELECTED]
, ProductOptionInformation.COMMENT AS [COMMENT]
, ProductOptionInformation.CATEGORY_PARENT_NAMES AS [CATEGORY_PARENT_NAMES]
, ProductOptionInformation.QUANTITY AS [QUANTITY]
, ProductOptionInformation.DEFAULT_QUANTITY AS [DEFAULT_QUANTITY]
, ProductOptionInformation.IS_PERCENTAGE_ADJUSTMENT AS [IS_PERCENTAGE_ADJUSTMENT]
, (CASE dbo.GetProductOptionInformation.IS_PERCENTAGE_ADJUSTMENT WHEN 1 THEN '%' ELSE '$' END) AS [IS_PERCENTAGE_ADJUSTMENT_TYPE]
, ProductOptionInformation.PRODUCT_SELL_PRICE AS [PRODUCT_SELL_PRICE]

FROM
     dbo.GetProductOptionInformation(NULL, NULL, CASE WHEN 386 = 385 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 'QuoteItem', 1) AS ProductOptionInformation

ORDER BY
  -- Default
  ProductOptionInformation.ID DESC
```

Please assist me in this

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the correct database ? Also this expression `CASE WHEN 386 = 385 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` will always return `0` , dont see the point of this expression ....

Comment: I was in the wrong database. After I corrected I got another error message as below

Comment: The multi-part identifier "dbo.GetProductOptionInformation.IS_PERCENTAGE_ADJUSTMENT" could not be bound.

Comment: I think the probelm is with this statement (CASE dbo.GetProductOptionInformation.IS_PERCENTAGE_ADJUSTMENT WHEN 1 THEN '%' ELSE '$' END) AS [IS_PERCENTAGE_ADJUSTMENT_TYPE]

Comment: Just use two part name and make sure your function has a  column with this name `GetProductOptionInformation.IS_PERCENTAGE_ADJUSTMENT`

Answer (score 1):

Try

> Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache.

Also, check your connection strings. They are probably pointing to an incorrect database.